# How to check the given text is already localized text or not in Swift?

Tags: swift, foundation

How to check the given text is already localized text or not in Swift?

Example:

```
var text = NSLocalizedString("str", comment: "any")
```

How to check if the variable 'text' is already localized?

Comment: change your localized string for "str" and see it updated or not?